# scaling a model in urdf

Tags: simulation, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a perfect working car model in urdf and now I wanted to scale it. I made a smaller robot so I wanted to scale them.
Is there a way to do it in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173546/scaling-a-model-in-urdf/) by [Dpp_coder](https://answers.ros.org/users/18691/dpp_coder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2014-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK this is not easily possible. While you can scale the individual link geometries, to scale the whole model, you´d need to also scale all translations that are part of the model in joints. Stringent use of [xacro](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) macros and properties throughout the model probably could make this easier (if not completely painless).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0